# How to download dynamic generated audio from Web Speech API (window.speechSynthesis.speak()) call?

Tags: javascript, audio, dynamic, download, speech-synthesis

I have this code right here which **download Dynamic generated Audio** from speechSynthesis API, But every time click the download button it says the file is not supported or the file extension is incorrect, So please can any one help me with this ?

```
const button = document.getElementById("a1")

button.addEventListener('click',function(data , name = "try.mp3"){
  
  var voiceVal =  synth.speak(speakText)

  const blob = new Blob([voiceVal], {type:"audio/mpeg"})
  const href = URL.createObjectURL(blob)

  const a = Object.assign(document.createElement('a'),  {
    href,
    style:"display:none",
    download:"try"

  });

  document.body.appendChild(a)

  a.click()
  URL.revokeObjectURL(href)
  a.remove()
})
```

Comment: What are you expecting `speechSynthesis.speak` to [return](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/SpeechSynthesis/speak#return_value)?

Comment: Actually , am expecting the text that passed to converted to a sound

Comment: If you read the docs I linked to you'll see it returns nothing.