# How to get data from tts audio in javascript?

Tags: javascript, text-to-speech

Hello I'm using Javascript Web Speech API. How to save an audio file from the text to speech of web speech api?
I found some posts which used google speech api or Azure TTS but I want to make it on Web Speech Api.
Any help is useful.

Comment: Same question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71373857/how-to-download-dynamic-generated-audio-from-web-speech-api-window-speechsynthe

Comment: In short, the answer is "**you can't**": as of 2023 [there is _absolutely nothing_ in the Web Speech API](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/SpeechSynthesis) that exposes generated audio to JS (this really surprised me...)